# Auto assign roles to 5k group members

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to assign 2 roles to 5k members in my server. I have tried using the following code but it's too slow. It gives roles to 5 members then waits for 7 seconds and then goes to the next members. I think it's discord API limit.

```
  roles = [discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=role) for role in 

        role_names]   


        for number, member in enumerate(message.server.members):
                    print(f"Giving role to member#{number}: {member}")
                    for role in roles:
                        try:
                            await client.add_roles(member, role)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
```

What should I do to make it work fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign multiple roles at the same time, but I don't think there's any way to assign roles to many people in the same API call.

```
await client.add_roles(member, *roles)
```